# Is the $1s$ state of Hydrogen eigenfunction of all the three of the Hamiltonian, the orbital angular momentum $\vec L$, and $L_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables, hydrogen, orbitals

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian, $\vec L$ the orbital angular momentum, and $L_z$ its projection on the z-axis.
Is the 1s state of Hydrogen an eigenfunction of all the three operators? I suppose it should be eigenfunction of $L_z$ and $H $ only.

Comment: This Question and Answer might be helpful to understand the special case of the s-orbital or more generally shared eigenvectors of non commuting operators, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656029/can-incompatible-observables-share-an-eigenvector

Answer (score 2):

The [orbital angular momentum operator in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Orbital_angular_momentum_in_spherical_coordinates) is
$$\vec{L}=i\hbar\left(
\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}
-\hat{\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
\right)$$
where $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ are the unit-vectors in $\theta$ and $\phi$ direction.

The $1s$ wavefunction of the hydrogen atom is spherically symmetric.
$$\psi_{1s}(r,\theta,\phi)=C e^{-r/a_0}$$

Because this wavefunction doesn't depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$ you have
$$\vec{L}\ \psi_{1s}(r,\theta,\phi)=\vec{0}$$

Hence the wavefunction is eigenfunction of $\vec{L}$
for eigenvalue $\vec{0}$.

Comment: And it is in fact, I believe, the *only* eigenvector of such.